# Issue with "Custom web view in File Dialog Box" in Office 2013

Tags: 2013, office

I have a custom “web view for file dialog” that used to work in Office 2010 and no longer works in the 2013 version.

By “web view for file dialog box” I mean the feature described here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms947923.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh967656(v=office.14).aspx

The issue is that, in Office 2013, it is only possible to navigate to a sub-path of the current location and not to other paths. Below is an example:

The user opens Microsoft Word, hits CTRL+S and enters “[portal url]/firstlib”
in the Save File Dialog;
A custom web view is displayed containing the following “links”:
    http://myportal.com/firstlib/folder1’ fileattribute=’folder’ …>…
    http://myportal.com/secondlib/folder1’ fileattribute=’folder’ …>…
    http://myportal.com/secondlib’ fileattribute=’folder’ …>…
The user clicks the first link. He gets properly redirected to [portal url]/firstlib/folder1 ;
Clicking the other two links doesn’t work properly. Instead of navigating to the link URLs, the file gets saved in the currently displayed location (i.e.,  "firstlib" )

As mentioned above, all links work properly in Office 2010 (Word, Excel).

I have checked this with the custom view implemented in both SP2010 (SP2) and SP2013 (SP2), so the issue seems to be on the client-side (Microsoft Office).

Would anybody know if this is a bug or a “feature”?

Or else, how could I implement navigation inside an Office Open/Save dialog. I’ve tried using “javascript:window.navigate(…)”,  “javascript:location.href=…” and “…”, but they cause a new IE window to pop up and the current location in the Open/Save dialog remains the same.

The issue can be reproduced by editing the file “[14 or 15 hive]\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\DocumentLibrary\DocLib\FileDlg.htm”, replacing the  tag with the following hard-coded table (make sure to replace the URL in there):

```
<table id="FileDialogViewTable" class="ms-allContentFileDlgView" style="cursor: default"   cellpadding="2" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr class="" fileattribute="folder" id=”http://myportal.com/secondlib" onmousedown="selectrow()" onclick="selectrow()">
<td valign="top" class="ms-vb2">Documents</td>
</tr>
</table>
```